# Hide gift card block in checkout basing on cart content

Tags: magento2, checkout, gift-card

I have to hide the "apply your gift card" block in the checkout/payment page. This should be hidden when the cart contains a gift card yet.
I found the HTML of this section, but I can't find where to set my conditions to display/hide the block.
I'm on Magento 2.